# Verifying a digital signature in Python, with optional CRL

Tags: python, openssl, signature

I want to be able to sign some data, and later verify the signature; I also want to use a CRL.

Right now, I'm using a small helper executable (written in C) to do all of this; I would prefer to do the entire thing in Python, since that's what the rest of the system is written in.

In the helper executable, I

- Create a store
- Load both the system root CA and our root CA into a store
- Load the CRL using:
  crl = d2i_X509_CRL_fp(crl, NULL);
  crl = PEM_read_X509_CRL(crl, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param = X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new();
  X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags(param, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK);
  X509_STORE_set1_param(store, param);
  X509_VERIFY_PARAM_free(param);
  X509_STORE_add_crl(store, crl);
- Read the certificate I want to verify against
- Verify said certificate against the store I set up before
- And then verify the signature against the certificate

I see that Python3.4 has an ability to load a CRL in OpenSSL.crypto, but then I don't see how I'd go about using it.

I hate to think I'm missing something obvious, but of course that's possible.

So... am I?  If so, what?

Added:  It looks like I have an outdated version of pyopenssl -- version 16.1.0 added a `add_crl` method to the `X509Store` class, so that may solve my problem.  (And looks like, the obvious thing I missed was checking the source repository!)

Comment: what have you tried? , can you add some code? can you explain how are you using the library/API?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not sure what to do.  I'm not using TLS or similar, so the SSL module there doesn't do much for me.  It's possible that I *can't*, but I would like to confirm that.  Or be told I'm stupid and here's this blindingly obvious way to do it.